# JAXB unmarshalling issue in Java

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Please, what could be wrong with my code..below is my menu class..

```
package commuinity;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Menu {

    String menu;
    String menuitem;
    String name;
    String action;


    public String getMenu() {
        return menu;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setMenu(String menu) {
        this.menu = menu;
    }
    public String getMenuitem() {
        return menuitem;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setMenuitem(String menuitem) {
        this.menuitem = menuitem;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getAction() {
        return action;
    }
    @XmlAttribute
    public void setAction(String action) {
        this.action = action;
    }



}
```

and here is my Jaxb utility class

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

public class JAXBExcer {

    public JAXBExcer(){


            try {
                File file = new File("sr/resources/file.xml");
                file.createNewFile();


            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Menu.class);

            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

             Menu menuApp= (Menu)jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);


            System.out.println(menuApp);

            }
            catch(IOException e){
                System.out.println("File is not created!");
            }

           catch (JAXBException e) {
            System.out.println("JaxB having issues!");
          }

        }

    }
```

The problem is it is not creating the file. It goes into the first catch phrase "File is not created" I tried then by creating it manually in my file system but then it jumps to the next catch phrase "JAXB having issues" Can anyone point me to the reason for this? I am just experimenting with JAXB. I was following the tutorial on this link:`http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/` 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unmarshalling is the process of converting XML to objects.  A [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) implementation expects the file to contain XML content.  Marshalling is the process of creating an XML file from objects and is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: Could you take a look at the step 4 :"Convert XML to Object" from this link :http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/
the customer class is similar to my Menu class. Could be there are other things the blogger did but so far, thatz what I was looking when writing mine.

Comment: @henryjoseph - Step 4 of that tutorial is reading in the file created from Step 3.

Comment: Hello @ Blaise, are you trying to say that the file that was passed into the Customer customer = (Customer) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file) line is from the step 3 file? if your answer is yes, then, that would mean for anyone to use the JAXB, he has to first marshall it before unmarshalling it? That wouldn't make much convinction to me as I just want to unmarshall an already existing XML file I downloaded from an external source and convert it to a Java Object. Couldn't i just create an empty file and pass it into the unmarshall() method?

Comment: @henryjoseph - Right, you want to unmarshal (convert XML to objects) an existing file, so that file needs to have content.  When marshalling (convert objects to XML) you could write objects to an empty file.

Comment: Thanks alot @Blaise. Now, I get the concept.

Comment: @henryjoseph - BTW there are many JAXB examples on my blog that you may find interesting:  http://blog.bdoughan.com